# querystring in URL is allowed or not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

my view have two dropdown and one submit buttom if no value is selected and if form get sumbited with GET method then my URL will be `http://localhost:53372/question/index?Index=List&type=&stage=&mid=1&mod=5`.

but i m applying an ActionFilter with `OnActionExcuting()` overriden method. so after submitting form URL is like `http://localhost:53372/question/index?index=List&mid=1&mod=5`.

**where other two QueryString is gone?**

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["mid"] == null || filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["mod"] == null)
        {
            mid = Convert.ToString(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Query)["mid"]);
            mod = Convert.ToString(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.Query)["mod"]);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mid) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mod))
            {
                RouteValueDictionary redirecttargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
                NameValueCollection Qstr = null;
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestType == "GET")
                {
                    Qstr = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Query);
                    foreach (string item in Qstr)
                    {
                        redirecttargetDictionary.Add(item, Qstr[item]);
                    }
                    if (Qstr["mid"] == null)
                    {
                        redirecttargetDictionary.Add("mid", mid);
                    }
                    if (Qstr["mod"] == null)
                    {
                        redirecttargetDictionary.Add("mod", mod);
                    }
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirecttargetDictionary);
                }
            }
        }           
    }
```

but if i select Dropdown value then all queryString is in URL.

QueryString with no values `stage=&type=` are not allowed?

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you are going to so much trouble to process the query string.  Maybe you  could explain that?

Answer (score 0):

By default MVC passes data as a query string unless you are submitting a form in which case the query string is bundled as part of the HttpRequest object.  You can access the query string directly using the `FormCollection` object or as part of the `HttpRequest` object.   The most direct way to access the query string is through the `FormCollection` object as follows
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitData(FormCollection form)
    {
        foreach(var key in form.AllKeys)
        {
            switch(key)
            {
                case "stage":
                    // do some work
                    break;
                case "type":
                    // do some more work
                    break;
             }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");
    }

I have seen empty query string values cause issues with some browsers (I think IE) under certain circumstances.   I suggest populating your DropDownList with a token instead of no value such as "Select..." and -1 for the value.

```
var dropDownList = new List<SelectListItem>();

dropDownList.Add(new SelectListItem{ Text = "Select", Value = "-1"} );
```

and then

```
@Html.DropDownList("stage", Model.Stages)
```

or something like that.

I hope this helps :)